# Call to a member function getRealPath() on string"

Tags: laravel-5.7, laravel-mail

I want send mail after submitting form with all data and with attachment(file,image).
I guess it returning string value . how to resolve this issues .

Controller.php

```
  $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            //upload image
            $path = $request->file('file')->storeAs('Circularfs',$fileNameToStore);
            //dd($path);
        }else{
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
        }
            $cfile = new circularfs;
            $cfile->title = $request->input('title');
            $cfile->department = $request->input('department');
            $cfile->file = $fileNameToStore;
            $cfile->save();

            $to_email = "abc@gmail.com";
            \Mail::to($to_email)->send(new \App\Mail\circularfs($cfile));
```

[App\Mail\circularfs.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmfXC.png) error screenshot is here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show your form code here?
Are you using this enctype="multipart/form-data" or 'files'=>true?

```
<form method="POST" action="http://example.com" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>

 {!! Form::open(['url' => route('myRoute'), 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true]) !!}
```

Comment: {!! Form::open(['url' => route('Circularfs.store'), 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true]) !!}
using this

Comment: Do var_dump($request->file('file'));

Comment: ->attach($this->cfile['file']->getRealPath(),
        [...]
I am getting error on this line and yes i dd($cfile) in constructor of customemail.php file data is coming

Comment: print the response of var_dump($request->file('file'));